# Paging with Firebase using PHP client

Tags: javascript, php, web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use [ktamas77/firebase-php](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php) client, which is based on `Firebase REST API` to bring the data from my real-time database to my website (based on `Yii 2` framework).

The point is that my database data grows gradually and will possibly reach less than `100 000` records until the project gets over. I'd like to ask you about the performance issues.

My goal is to implement paging of the data I get from `API`. So till now I want to get all the data in one request and store it in session, and then with the help of `Yii2` tools make paging on this array I store. I'm not sure if this is a good idea and how it will affect the performance of my website.

I know it's quite tricky to attempt get paged data from `Firebase`, that is why I'd like to implement it on `PHP`.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really making sense. Firebase can be accessed with [JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/).

Comment: @PHPglue, yes, but what about paging?

Comment: Maybe [.endAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#endAt)? In other words use their JavaScript API before you make changes to your DOM.

Comment: Ok, but if I store the data, just interesting, is it a problem for a browser?